# How to copy a Postgres database within the same DB cluster?

Tags: postgresql, replication

I want to replicate a Postgres database without dumping data using `pg_dump`. Both source and target database are on the same machine (Test and Production server).

I would like to create a `master_db_copy` as exact copy of the production server `master_db`.

I tried from the command line:

```
pg_dump -vO master_db | gzip > master_db
gunzip -cV master_db.sql.gz | psql master_db_copy
```

Is there a better / faster way?

Comment: You can use `pg_basebackup` for that: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgbasebackup.html

Comment: What is the problem with pg_dump? Do you really need to create the compressed file? Otherwise you can simply do `pg_dump -vO master_db | psql master_db_copy`, which would run considerably faster.

Comment: Hi ziggy , this is exactly the solution I was looking for. Never occurred in my mind. Really simple idea it is.   However it didn't work when I tried .

Comment: This did the trick for me: CREATE DATABASE newdb WITH TEMPLATE originaldb

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The fastest way to copy a complete database within the same DB cluster is [`CREATE DATABASE` with a `TEMPLATE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createdatabase.html). This just copies a whole DB on the file level.

```
CREATE DATABASE master_db_copy TEMPLATE master_db;
```

You must be superuser or owner of the template (`master_db` in the example) - unless it's marked as dedicated template in `pg_database.datistemplate`.

And the template cannot have concurrent connections to it. Dedicated template databases make sure of this by setting `pg_database.datallowconn`. You might use `pg_terminate_backend()` to close connections. See:

- [How to clone a test database from a production one in one single action?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10107602/939860)

[The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/manage-ag-templatedbs.html)

> Two useful flags exist in `pg_database` for each database: the columns
> `datistemplate` and `datallowconn`. `datistemplate` can be set to
> indicate that a database is intended as a template for `CREATE DATABASE`. If this flag is set, the database can be cloned by any user
> with `CREATEDB` privileges; if it is not set, only superusers and the
> owner of the database can clone it. If `datallowconn` is false, then
> no new connections to that database will be allowed (but existing
> sessions are not terminated simply by setting the flag false).
> `datistemplate = true`. [...]

Comment: Note that from https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/manage-ag-templatedbs.html it looks like you should set datistemplate = true if you want to do this from a non-superuser account.

Comment: how much slower will be creating copies of schema? I mean the case where I don't need data inside just, definitions, to play with stuff in concurrent threads in tests.

Comment: @beldaz: Thanks, I updated to address that.

Comment: @andilabs; Without any data, copying a schema is typically *very fast*. You might pipe the output of `pg_dump` to `psql` directly. Basically: `pg_dump --schema-only --schema template_schema mydb | psql mydb`. Be aware that "schema" is used in two different meanings here. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11103279/939860, https://stackoverflow.com/q/12564777/939860